# Codecov: error processing coverage reports

Tags: pytest, code-coverage, travis-ci, codecov

I want to add codecov to [this project](https://github.com/HumanCapitalAnalysis/thesis-projects-tostenzel/tree/ec7f874a2663bdad5a126bb028194c2b562e1868). Yet, codecov says [here](https://codecov.io/gh/HumanCapitalAnalysis/thesis-projects-tostenzel/commit/ec7f874a2663bdad5a126bb028194c2b562e1868) that it can not process my coverage.xml file that I created with this command: `pytest python/tests -v --junitxml=coverage.xml` in the Travis CI script.

Everything prior to that like providing my token seems to work as suggested in the TravisCI build [here](https://travis-ci.org/HumanCapitalAnalysis/thesis-projects-tostenzel/jobs/642690377).

I thought this could perhaps be a problem with the paths but I included a potential fix in the `codecov.yml` and nothing changed.

Therefore, I do not think that the script `codecov.yml`, `travis.yml`, and `utils/travis_runner.py` are part of the problem.

Comment: Voting to close, please use https://community.codecov.io/ for Codecov support questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--junitxml` option is for generating reports in JUnit format. Use the option `--cov-report` to generate coverage reports. `pytest-cov` allows passing `--cov-report` multiple times to generate reports in different formats. Example:

```
$ pip install pytest pytest-cov
$ pytest --cov=mypkg --cov-report term --cov-report xml:coverage.xml
```

will print the coverage table and generate the Cobertura XML report which is CodeCov-compatible.

Comment: Glad I could help!